# Make bootstrap popover overlap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is I am using bootstrap's popover for an image, using the hover as trigger, while at the same time, I'm using the Smoothdivscroll (http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/#quickdemo) but the problem is, that part of the popover is hidden.

Example https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/2a3e0g0J1K0O3l3m0u2C/Screen%20Shot%202013-01-31%20at%2020.01.06.png?v=cf069cc3
As you can see, part of the popover (right side) is hidden under the div. The problem is minimal in the screenshot, but when I put it on the last image you can't see it at all.

I tried changing the z-index but it didn't work.

Popover's default code:

```
.popover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1010;
  display: none;
  width: 236px;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: normal;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
          border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
     -moz-background-clip: padding;
          background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

SmoothDivScroll default code:

```
div.scrollWrapper {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using ?

Comment: I am using the latest version, I downloaded it from their site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [display bootstrap popovers outside divs with overflow:hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194705/display-bootstrap-popovers-outside-divs-with-overflowhidden)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since some changes were made to the way the tooltips and popovers are included (see [this commit](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/commit/88b1e44dd61afd8f08761346555521bd216ed73a#L2L124)), there has been bugs about overflowing elements.

We could tweak your markup to make it work, with some `overflow: visible` but a fix will be available in the next version (2.3.0) as shown by [this commit](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/commit/d594d6377a7e9cda399c25a450b0d27df704d939#L0L129).

Simply put, you can download the next version or apply the changes of the commit to your files to allow your popover to be used like that :

```js
$('.popover').popover({
    container: 'body'
});
```

Or use the data attibutes : `data-container="body"`.

Comment: I have changed the bootstrap-tooltip.js to match the new changes and the jQuery code, but I don't understand where to put `overflow: visible` code

Comment: @CodexVideos The JS fix plus the `container: 'body'` option should be enough. Have you tried ? I'm not even sure we could solve the problem with `overflow: visible` so don't put it anywhere.

Comment: I replaced my whole old one with the new one and I this is my jQuery code: 
`$(".poster").popover({ html : false, container: 'body'});`

Comment: I was thinking maybe the 2 plugins interfere with each other.

Comment: Which one did you updated ? I think you should either replace only the [lines mentioned](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/commit/d594d6377a7e9cda399c25a450b0d27df704d939#L0L129). Or replace `bootstrap-tooltip.js` **and** `bootstrap-popover.js` ([see here](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/d594d6377a7e9cda399c25a450b0d27df704d939/js)) and you should not have both `bootstrap[.min].js` and those files included in the same page.

Comment: I have updated both bootstrap-tooltip.js and bootstrap-popover.js (I don't use .min version). But it's still the same problem.

Comment: I know that if I remove `overflow: hidden`, it gets solved but then the 'SmoothDivScroll' doesn't work.

Comment: Redo your includes from scratch, because it seems to work : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/d8YNP/)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, turns out you had right the whole time, I had a simple typo in my code, instead of `script` I had written `scirpt`. It works now, marking you as my answer.