# Bootstrap PopConfirm popovers don't show above a <div> where overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.1 and the [PopConfirm plug-in](https://github.com/AnaelFavre/PopConfirm) to provide confirmations before submitting a form.

When a regular Bootstrap popover is called from a button inside a `<div>` where the CSS has been set to `overflow:hidden;` it properly displays the entire popover above the `<div>` from inside which it was called:

[image: happy popover]

But, when a PopConfirm popover is called from a button inside a `<div>` where the CSS has been set to `overflow:hidden;` it is not properly shown above the `<div>` from where it was called:

[image: sad popconfirm popover] (http://jsfiddle.net/bhall7x/Y4t8a/1/)

Is there a way to somehow get the PopConfirm popover to display above all other elements, even if the `<div>` from which it was called is set to `overflow:hidden;`?

See also: https://github.com/AnaelFavre/PopConfirm/issues/4

Comment: If you need to trigger an instance of PopConfirm from within a modal, be sure to set `container: false` in your JavaScript/jQuery, otherwise the default is `container: body`, which will show behind the modal (http://jsfiddle.net/bhall7x/Y4t8a/10/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [display bootstrap popovers outside divs with overflow:hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194705/display-bootstrap-popovers-outside-divs-with-overflowhidden)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question : [Make bootstrap popover overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633364/make-bootstrap-popover-overlap) i found the solution.

I added a "container" parameter to the lastest version. Please use the lastest version available in the github.

Comment: Yes! The problem was that we just needed to add `container: 'body'` to the PopConfirm defaults. Thanks!

Comment: Be sure to set `container: false` if you are triggering PopConfirm from within a modal so that the PopConfirm popover isn't hidden behind the modal. (http://jsfiddle.net/bhall7x/Y4t8a/10/)

Answer (score 2):

set  option `container: 'body'`

```
$(".btn-relist").popover({
    title: "Relist",
    content: "Relist item?",
    placement: "top",
    container: 'body'
});
```

I hope it will help you.